# How to interpret the TensorFlow Lite benchmark app results?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have used the TensorFlow Lite benchmark app, and I got the following result:

```
E tflite  : Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 119501, Init: 3556, Inference: 135968, Overall max resident set size = 32.0469 MB, total malloc-ed size = 0 MB, in-use allocated/mmapped size = 13.3229 MB
```

I would like to know what does mean these values: *Warmup*, *Init*, *Inference*, *Overall max resident set size*, *total malloc-ed size* and *in-use allocated/mmapped size*.

I didn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For latencies

- Warmup: The latency for the first warmup invocation. Note the latency of the very first invocation may be slower since the code may do extra initialization / allocation
- Init: Initialization time (to create the TensorFlow Lite interpreter)
- Inference: The average of the inference invocation. This should be the most important metrics in most cases.